# How to ALTER....CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT using PowerShell and SMO

Tags: powershell, smo

I have a PowerShell script that checks if the Constraint is enabled and checked. I want to add a step to do the equivalent of "ALTER.....CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT" but I'm not finding any MS SMO documentation relating to this. 
How I can do this using PowerShell and SMO?

This gives the information of current state of constraints.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo') | Out-Null
$Srv = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" $SqlServer
$srv.Databases | % { 
    $Database = $_.Name
    $_.Tables | % {
           $_.Checks | % {
            "Database $Database Table $($_.Parent.Name) constraint $($_.Name)`n$($_.Text)  `nIsChecked: $($_.IsChecked) "
           }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to me that SMO offers a method to the foreignkey/default constraint objects. 
You'll probably need to do something with a sql call using Dbcc CheckConstraint. Doing something programmatically though is a bit of bore.

When I run into a stumbling block like this I tend to look to the great work the dbatools folks are doing for help.

Assuming you don't want to use the whole dbatools module you can generally grab the command being generated out of their established modules. I find their hard work with the results of the output of the command to be most helpful.

https://docs.dbatools.io/#Invoke-DbaDbDbccCheckConstraint

Look at the github code for that logic - it'll help assuming you want to collect / output the results of the DbccCheckConstraint call.

https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/blob/development/functions/Invoke-DbaDbDbccCheckConstraint.ps1